# Git feature branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I follow https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows for Git Workflow, so I have **master**, **develop** and **feature-one** branches for my current project.

I have developed some codes in **feature-one** branch and not committed them yet. Now I like to create another feature branch called **feature-two** to develop and test some new code.

My problem is that the new, uncommitted code from **feature-one** branch is available in all branches and when I create a new feature branch (here feature-two) from develop branch, it includes the new codes from **feature-one** branch too.

1. How can I get a new branch without the new, uncommitted code from other branches?
2. How can I delete the **feature-one** with all its new code and modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either commit the uncommitted code, so you don’t lose it (remember: uncommitted code does *not* exist in the Git repository, so deleting it will be permanent!), or you can [stash it](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) so you can continue working on it later.

To delete a branch, you can use `git branch -d branchname`. This will only work if you have merged the changes in somewhere else (e.g. master or develop), so again, you don’t lose any work. If you want to delete it anyway, you can use `git branch -D` (upper case D) instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer. when I commit the changes in feature-one branch, the changes won't be availbe in develp branch? I do not want to touch any codes in develop branch. It is stable now. I am only testing some codes in feature branches.

Comment: No, that’s the whole point of branches. Commits you create while on some branch will be added to that branch only. So by creating branches, you can work on independent things separately (while happily creating more commits on the branches), and only when you are done, you merge that branch back into develop and as such integrate those changes there.